# Unique QUERY based on IFS, AND formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 4 different queries that pull different columns of data.

I would like to create an IFS, AND formula on some checkboxes. Based on what checkbox is clicked, I would like it to execute the specific query.

I am getting the error:

- `IFS has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 1. column count: 1. Actual row count: 20, column count: 2.`

Here is a working example of my formula (IFS, AND, **without** QUERY)

```
=IFS(
  AND(E3=TRUE,F3=TRUE),"Both boxes are checked. (TRUE/TRUE)",
  AND(E3=FALSE,F3=FALSE),"Both boxes are unchecked. (FALSE/FALSE)",
  AND(E3=TRUE,F3=FALSE),"First box is checked. (TRUE/FALSE)",
  AND(E3=FALSE,F3=TRUE),"Second box is checked. (FALSE/TRUE)"
)
```

Here is the non-working version of my formula (IFS, AND, **with** QUERY)

```
=IFS(
  AND(E3=TRUE,F3=TRUE),QUERY(J1:K),
  AND(E3=FALSE,F3=FALSE),QUERY(L1:M),
  AND(E3=TRUE,F3=FALSE),QUERY(N1:O),
  AND(E3=FALSE,F3=TRUE),QUERY(P1:Q)
)
```

Why is this formula breaking when I introduce query?

[Click Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O0YEETmdC2Lk74mTM9TIJfE6XDKoKpB_440NML2KEHQ/edit?usp=sharing) - to view my Google Sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IFS` within an `ArrayFormula` does not behave as nested `IF`s do in an `ArrayFormula`

You will have to use nested `IF`s for your formula.

Try the following

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(AND(E3=true,F3=true),J3:K,
              IF(AND(E3=FALSE,F3=FALSE),L3:M,
              IF(AND(E3=true,F3=FALSE),N3:O,
              IF(AND(E3=FALSE,F3=true),P3:Q)))))
```

[image]

You also notice that the `QUERY` function is not needed because you do not actually use it.

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you! As for the query, in the example worksheet, I did not want to over complicate the formula to demonstrate the issue. In the real sheet, I am using querying to retrieve specific rows based on multiple criteria. I have added back the query formula and your formula still works! Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help.